# Есть ли в PHPStorm такие же "слои", как sublime?

Tags: phpstorm, sublime-text

В sublime text есть интересная фишка: если нажать alt+shift+3, alt+shift+3 и т.д., то экран поделится на несколько кусков (слоев) с разными открытыми файлам.

Есть ли такое в шторме, хотя бы на уровне плагинов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Клик правой на вкладку -> `Split Vertically` / `Split Horizontally`.
Вместо клика можно нажать `Ctrl+Shift+A` и ввести `Split`..

Answer (score 2):

Конечно же, есть, [без всяких плагинов](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/splitting-and-unsplitting-editor-window.html).

Comment: почему то не могу отетить ваш ответ ка кправильный((

Comment: @Артур Пантелеев, вы можете выбрать только один правильный ответ.